# Как задать цвет Statusbar при использовании RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Использую RelativeLayout. В ней ToolBar, и 2 LinearLayout. Подскажите, как задать цвет statusBar.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mindzone.wireframedemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
    <LinearLayout>
...
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
...
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменить цвет можно при API>=21. Программно:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;         
if(sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_statusbar_color));
}
```

Документация:
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)

Answer (score 1):

### styles.xml

В вашем стиле:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#22702a</item>
```